# git checkout specific files

Tags: awk, grep, git, xargs

In the moment, when I run `git status`, I got

```
modified:   loanwolf/alerts/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/alerts/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/clientspace/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/clientspace/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/configurations/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/configurations/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/contracts/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/contracts/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/contrib/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/contrib/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/core/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/core/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/core/templatetags/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/core/templatetags/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/customers/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/customers/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/customers/models.py
modified:   loanwolf/dashboard/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/dashboard/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/documents/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/documents/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/employees/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/employees/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/equifax_report/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/equifax_report/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/loans/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/loans/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/messaging/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/messaging/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/notes/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/notes/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/operations/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/operations/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/perception/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/perception/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/products/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/products/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/requests/models.py
modified:   loanwolf/statistics/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/statistics/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
modified:   loanwolf/users/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo
modified:   loanwolf/users/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

I want to clean the output to remove `modified:` and the files

```
loanwolf/requests/models.py
loanwolf/customers/models.py
loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
```

In fact, I want to keep all the file except those three last. How could I do that?

For the moment, I think I could do `git status | grep -v 'request'`. I want to `git checkout` all files except those three files.

`git status | grep 'modified:' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git [diff|add|checkout]` ????

Comment: How are you picking out those 3 files??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328065/unix-using-grep-to-get-unmatched-lines ... I gues we could do that.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it this way:

- commit the files you want to keep (temporarily)

  ```
  git commit -m WIP loanwolf/requests/models.py loanwolf/customers/models.py loanwolf/requests/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
  ```
- check everything else out

  ```
  git checkout .
  ```
- reset to undo the commit (this won’t lose any changes)

  ```
  git reset HEAD^1
  ```

If you do want to play around with `git status`, check out `git status -s`, its output is easier to process reliably.

Comment: You could probably also use a "stash"? I've done that myself, but only once or twice with a GUI. It basically means you're stashing some file away for a while, then you pull the latest commits, then apply the stashed files to the repository.

Comment: @Kusalananda a stash would be more convenient, but `git stash` stores the complete workspace state, it can’t filter (AFAIK). You’re right though that my use of a commit here is more akin to a stash than a proper commit. Some GUIs have stashing variants that support filtering, those would work too.